# Sorting through NSDictionary with complex .plist in Swift

Tags: swift

Learning Swift and having some trouble parsing through a plist that is a NSDictionary.

I am looking at building a test app that pulls the URLString of Safari's reading list from the ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist.

I can read the data in xCode using the below:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application


    let location = "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist".stringByExpandingTildeInPath
    var error: NSError?

    var plistArray = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: location)
    println(plistArray)
    }
```

The diffuculty I am having is being able to irrated with a loop over the Dictionary and pull the values I need from the Reading List.  Below is the format of the plist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Children</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>History</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkIdentifier</key>
            <string>History</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
            <string>WebBookmarkTypeProxy</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
            <string>77F746D5-FAE9-453F-BB61-20C6709321C3</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Children</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>URIDictionary</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>title</key>
                        <string>Yelp</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>URLString</key>
                    <string>http://www.yelp.com/</string>
                    <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
                    <string>WebBookmarkTypeLeaf</string>
                    <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
                    <string>5EF3DFF8-909D-400C-9738-78EC9BCDB8FD</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>BookmarksBar</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
            <string>WebBookmarkTypeList</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
            <string>81E022A4-9F93-4D52-8516-29D4833349F2</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>BookmarksMenu</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
            <string>WebBookmarkTypeList</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
            <string>522EFC56-F2B2-400D-B718-6C9430473FD8</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Children</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>ReadingList</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>DateAdded</key>
                        <date>2015-07-02T17:50:27Z</date>
                        <key>PreviewText</key>
                        <string>Overview This article explains how to start and stop Tomcat on the JSS host server. There are different ways to start and stop Tomcat depending on the version of the Casper Suite that you are running and the platform on</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>ReadingListNonSync</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>AddedLocally</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>ArchiveOnDisk</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>DateLastFetched</key>
                        <date>2015-07-02T17:50:30Z</date>
                        <key>FetchResult</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                    </dict>
                    <key>URIDictionary</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>title</key>
                        <string>Starting and Stopping Tomcat</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>URLString</key>
                <string>https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/article.html?id=117</string>
                    <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
                    <string>WebBookmarkTypeLeaf</string>
                    <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
                    <string>0F579C8E-FD60-4AF2-92F3-AC6929465B6F</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>ShouldOmitFromUI</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>com.apple.ReadingList</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
            <string>WebBookmarkTypeList</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
            <string>9406BEF1-FEED-41EE-AF05-AA599B9DD7B1</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>WebBookmarkFileVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
    <string>WebBookmarkTypeList</string>
    <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
    <string>A9E09D59-9251-406A-B743-42E5B75FC170</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am trying to get the url of the link in the reading list section.  Specifically:

```
<string>https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/article.html?id=117</string>
```

What is the correct way of doing this in swift?  Every for loop I use returns errors of no subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have here's how you would do it with Swift 2:

```
let location = "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist".stringByExpandingTildeInPath

guard let childrenArray = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: location)?.objectForKey("Children") as? [[NSObject : AnyObject]]
else
{
    // TODO: Handle error file couldn't be read.
    return
}
var URLs = [String]()
for child in childrenArray
{
    guard let subChildren = child["Children"] as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]]
    else { continue }
    for subChild in subChildren
    {
        guard let URL = subChild["URLString"] as? String
        else { continue }
        URLs.append(URL)
    }
}
print(URLs)
// The URLs array will have the link you are looking for.
```

If you aren't using swift 2 change all the guards to if let constructs and whatever comes after the else part of the guard should go inside the if let construct. Let me know if you have any related questions. The URLs array will have the URL you are looking for as a string.

Comment: Worked well.  Had to modify a little for swift, since i'm not using 2.  This gave a great example of how to parse through a file.  Thanks